# How to load multiple images as command line arguments to sprintf() and cvLoadImage() in OpenCV...?

Tags: c, visual-studio, opencv, image-processing

This is the code i have., which will detect the faces in the image and draws rectangle around the face.

```
CvHaarClassifierCascade *cascade;
CvMemStorage *storage;
void detectFaces (IplImage *newframe);
int key;
int iImg;
int Num_Images=20;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
string filename = M:/Trend/FaceDetection/MyCascadeFolder/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml";
storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0) ;   
cascade = ( CvHaarClassifierCascade* )cvLoad( filename.c_str());

**//to load a single image**
**IplImage* inImage = cvLoadImage("M:/Trend/FaceDetection775/MyImages/face1.jpg",1);**

//IplImage* inImage = cvLoadImage(argv[1],1); >> It also works fine through command line

detectFaces( inImage );
cvShowImage("FaceDetection2",inImage);
cvSaveImage("M:/FaceDetection/MyImages/OpImages/faces.jpg",inImage);
cvReleaseImage( &inImage);              

// **to load no. of images or a complete folder**
char buf[20];       
for(iImg=0; iImg<=Num_Images; iImg++)  
{
**sprintf(buf, "M:/FaceDetection/ImagesFolder/P%04d.jpg", iImg);**                      
*// sprintf(buf, argv[2], iImg); // I Tried with this., but its not working*

 printf("\n");      
inImage = cvLoadImage(buf, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);  
printf("Input Image = P%04d.jpg\n", iImg);              
detectFaces( inImage );
cvShowImage("FaceDetection",inImage);
cvReleaseImage( &inImage );                 
key= cvWaitKey(0);
if ( key == 'q' || key == 'Q' )
return(0);
}

cvReleaseHaarClassifierCascade( &cascade );
cvReleaseMemStorage( &storage );
return 0;
}

**// the actual detectfaces() function goes like this**
void detectFaces( IplImage *newframe)
{
CvSeq *faces = cvHaarDetectObjects( newframe, cascade, storage, 1.15, 5, 0,   cvSize( 30, 30 ) );
    for( int i = 0 ; i < ( faces ? faces->total : 0 ) ; i++ )
    {
    CvRect *r = ( CvRect *)cvGetSeqElem( faces, i );
    cvRectangle(newframe,cvPoint( r->x, r->y ),cvPoint( r->x + r->width, r->y + r->height ),CV_RGB( 0, 255, 0 ), 2, 8, 0 );  
    }
}
```

Here., sprintf() method is taking multiple images statically (within the program itself). But I want to pass those multiple images as a single folder through command line argument.

I try to use cvLoadImage() function, but it also takes only one image as input instead of a folder.

Also I am not able to count the number of rectangles it draws for every single face in the image., how can I do that also...?

Please help me in this regards.

I am working on face detection project *"www.MahdiRezaei.com"* for my academics., and I am using visual studio-2010 with C, C++ and OpenCV.

Thankz in advance.

Comment: Hi there !! Can you please format your code to make it more readable.

Comment: please use opencv's c++ api, the legacy c-api is a dead end.

Comment: hi @SouravGhosh thankz., I have formatted the code. check it out and help me.

Comment: hi @berak thankz. I will check it out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can change the following code to use it with arguments.

```
#include<Windows.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
WIN32_FIND_DATA data;

HANDLE h = FindFirstFile(L"c:\\Images\\*.*", &data); // first file is the current directory
FindNextFile(h, &data);                                 //second file is the parent directory
vector<Mat> Images;
if (h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    while (FindNextFile(h, &data))
    {
        string filename = data.cFileName;
        sprintf(filename, "%s%s","C:\\Images\\", filename.c_str());
        Images.push_back(imread(filename, 1));
        delete[] nPtr;

    } 
}
else
    cout << "Error: No such folder." << endl;

FindClose(h);
return 0;
```

}